# htaccess Block Curl/Wget for all but IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way I can block all access to curl and wget requests, but still allow an IP address through?

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pycurl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [NC,OR]
```

While these definately do the blocking, I'd like to be able to allow 1 IP address to utilize these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the conditions to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pycurl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
```

where the 1.2.3.4 is the IP you don't want to block.